# LogisticRegression игнорирует заданное количество воркеров (n_jobs), занимая все процессы

Tags: python, sklearn

При запуске обучения модели логистической регрессии из sklearn LogisticRegression/LogisticRegressionCV занимаются все процессы, хотя при инициализации я задаю меньшее количество процессов на использование (даже если ставлю флаг None, что по документации значит n_jobs=1, 64 процесса заполняются полностью).

Comment: А вы используете LR прямо вот одну саму по себе или внутри какого-то пайплайна? Хотелось бы увидеть тот фрагмент кода, где вы инстанциируете и вызываете LR. И я бы попробовал явно выставить `n_jobs=1`.

Comment: C n_jobs все не так просто, если почитать документацию - https://scikit-learn.org/stable/computing/parallelism.html. Попробуйте ограничить ресурсы вашей модели с помощью описанной там переменной среды `OMP_NUM_THREADS`

Comment: вы пробовали задать `n_jobs=1` __явно__?

Comment: Спасибо за комментарии, @MaxU да, я пробовала задавать явно количество n_jobs, это не помогло. Путем перебора заданных параметров проблема оказалась в параметре solver, т.е. в оптимизаторе.

Comment: Судя по документации  от @ClickName, там проблема в том, что n_jobs  создает процессы на уровне питона, то есть параллелит fit модели, внутри которой запускается оптимизатор, в котором векторные вычисления ```via OpenMP, used in C or Cython code```, они вот занимают все ресурсы, если количество процессов для этих либ не задать явно, что написано в комменте выше. Ну и судя по всему эти штуки не задокументированы пока.